# How to understand RootViewController in Page-Based Application Template?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a Page-based Application in Xcode 5 using Apple's template. Where Can I find useful information to let me understand the following code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    DataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil]; 

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self.modelController;

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

    CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
}
```

Comment: *...but it will be very helpful for me!!!* Perhaps, but it will be even more helpful for you to research the answers yourself. Apple provides excellent documentation that's accessible directly from Xcode. Things like the property assignments and method calls you point to are easy to decipher if you look them up -- just select the item in question and take a look at Xcode's Quick Help inspector to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController]; // <--what does it mean???
> ```

Everything is explained in the `UIPageViewController` documentation, especially [here in the `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010891-CH1-SW2). **See the table that explain every possible case**.

In particular, an `UIPageViewController` presents either one or two View Controllers, depending on if they are one or two-sided. That's why the property is an array, as it expects an `NSArray` of either one or two ViewController(s) to display.

---

[EDIT] As you edited your post to add questions on about every line of the code, we can't answer them all in one simple SO answer. There is simply too many concepts here.

You will probably need either to get a book about iOS Programming to **explain all the basic concepts here**, or read the "View Controller Programming Guide" documentation on Apple website, and all the other Apple documentation on each concepts, like:

- What is a Storyboard (see User Interfaces Programming Guide)
- What are the concepts of a delegate and a dataSource (see Apple's DevPedia and Design Patters Programming Guide)
- What are the concepts of subviews and how does the View Hierarchy work in Cocoa (see the "View Programming Guide") and how the coordinate system of views work (like bounds and frames, see same documentation)
- How does View Controller Containers work (see the View Controller Programming Guide)
- How do Touch detection and Gestures work (see Touch and Gestures Programming Guide)

**That's really a lot to explain and to ask in one SO question, and that's also a lot of questions about some very basics of CocoaTouch and iOS programming, better explained in dedicated tutorial or books and Programming Guides for each subject each!!**

Comment: but what does this mean?
`[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];`
I think PageViewController holds an Array of childViewController, why add pageViewController to ChildViewController???

Comment: See my EDIT. There is really too much to explain here in a simple SO answer, you really seem to lack understanding of a lot of CocoaTouch basic concepts like storyboard, view bounds, view hierarchy concepts, view controller containers pattern (see View Controllers Programming guide for this specific one), datasource & delegate patterns… there is quite a question for each line even the ones that concerns the basics, so my advice is to get a good book on iOS programming and learn each concept at a time, you can't learn all those concepts in one simple SO answer, that's simply too much to explain